# JavaFX + Sprint Boot 2.0.1. Не работает подстановка значений/объектов внутри @Component

Tags: javafx, spring-boot

Исходники приложения с проблемой: [github](https://github.com/BleStaR/assistant-architecture.git)

Проблема: в классе `ru.blestar.ui.StartView` не срабатывают аннотации `@Value`/`@Resource`/`@Autowired`. Причем, если `@Autowired` прописать на конструктор, а не на поле, тогда она работает (например, если `resourcesUtil` передавать через конструктор). Как исправить эту проблему?

P.S.: Класс `ru.blestar.ui.StartView` видится как компонент/бин и подставляется в класс `ru.blestar.App` (в этом можно убедиться, запустив приложение)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь в конструкторе спринг бина использовать поля, которые должны быть проинициализированы спрингом. В момент создания класса эти поля еще не определены. Другими словами спринг сначала создает инстанс бина, а затем обрабатывает аннотации.

Передалайте конструктор класса `StartView` в метод, который будет вызван после инизиализации бина (для этого необходимо воспользоваться аннотацией `@PostConstruct`) и вы получите желаемый результат.

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    Button button = new Button(buttonText);
    getChildren().add(button);

    if (resourcesUtil == null) {
        log.error("ResourcesUtil is null. In class {}", getClass());
    }
}
```